# save image after cropping in android

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera

am trying to save cropped image and it is successfully being saved but the problem is that the saved image is too small. I want to get the original dimension of cropped image. here is my code for saving cropped image.

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
 Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());
 try {
f.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
fo.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

can any one help me to get high quality cropped image. any help would be much appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: You are saving exactly what you get; with highest quality for that format. Not much to improve there.

Comment: I've seen many apps with high quality resolution cropped images, there should be some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the size of the original image and the size you crop the image to.

One way of cropping is this:

```
               Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scaleType", "centerCrop");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

                //....snip....
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
                //....snip....

                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getBackgroundUri());
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ActivityCrop);
```

With this you always get a square image (aspect = 1) of the size 400px (output = 400).
So if you select a 800px square of the image it will be scaled down, losing quality.
On the contrary selecting a 50px square will also get you 400px in the result.

Now if you cut out the size restriction (right there at the dotted line). you will get the originally selected area back(800 and 50 for the examples) and with it the best possible quality.

Comment: how i can cut out the size restriction?

Comment: They are between the two "snip" comments. The extras "outputX" and "outputY" set the output size for this intent.

Comment: what should be the size of extras "outputX" and "outputY" to cut out size restriction. thanks for your reply, it is very much appreciated :)

Comment: I meant to leave out those two lines of code completely. This way you get exactly what you selected during cropping.

Answer (score 1):

send crop intent with aspect ratio and size

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

On Activity result

```
if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i1.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bb11 = drawable.getBitmap();



            File sdCardDirectory = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "MFA - AFTER - CROP");

            if (!sdCardDirectory.exists()) {
                if (!sdCardDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("MySnaps", "failed to create directory");

                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                    .format(new Date());

            String nw = "MFA_CROP_" + timeStamp + ".jpeg";

            File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, nw);

            boolean success = false;

            // Encode the file as a PNG image.
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                bb11.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                success = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            b7.setEnabled(true);

        }
```

HappY CodinG :)

Comment: atline  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i1.getDrawable();  what is i1?

Comment: i1 is imageview , that i used in my coding.  
This just to get idea , how to do .

Comment: works perfectly, don't know why you are not upvoted. Thanks Kathir

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

```html
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
   intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
   intent.putExtra("outputX", 320);
   intent.putExtra("outputY", 470);
   intent.putExtra("aspectX", 320);
   intent.putExtra("aspectY", 470);
   intent.putExtra("scale", true);
   intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

referred from this site

[Screen resolution for different devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)